# Spring Boot without Model + MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I need to make an application without using models, because it require to make an model for every tables - which isn't needed for me.

We can go with a class which execute the queries directly or Rest API.

Has anyone have any idea for achieving this?

Comment: Hi,

Please provide tutorial or example if anyone have.

Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a idea providing service. Also, what have you done till now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in other answers, you do not require `Models`.

See this Spring Boot [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) and you can download a simple [working example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/)

1. You need to have `application.properties` file with the properties below

> ```
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
> spring.datasource.username=dbuser
> spring.datasource.password=dbpass
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
> ```

2. Add spring boot jdbc dependency in your `pom.xml`

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. You want to inject `jdbcTemplate` in your controller class or any other 
   component scanned class,

> ```
> private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
>
>  @Autowired
>  public MyController(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
>     this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
>  }
> ```

In this way you can autowire jdbcTemplate in any spring bean.

Comment: HI,

Thank you for reply but what i need to do like whole form post data insert directly into database table without using variables like as id, firstName and lastName as per document.

Moral of the story is i don't need "Customer.java" as per document.
I hope you getting my point.

Comment: You can use #3 in your controller class to get the jdbcTemplate instance. Then you should get the form data in one of the controller method and  in the same method you can use `jdbcTemplate` instance to insert the records in the database. Check this [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-)  API Documentation

Comment: Hi,

Thank you so much.

Comment: I understand you point but can you give me one example for insert update delete with controller which you talking abou.

Comment: Hi,

Please provide me a demo if you have because i have tried but i'm fail so please...

Comment: I am little busy right now...but will provide u by end of the day today...

Comment: Thank you so much for help me.

Comment: Added a simple project in GitHub - https://github.com/omkar999/SpringBootFormSubmissionApp

Comment: Thank you so much..
This is what i'm looking for..
Thank you once  again..

Comment: Hi,
How to get whole FORM POST array in Controller?
Please Advice.

Comment: Hi,

I'm fail to display all data from database.
I have done with get all data from database but how to display in html table that i don't know.
So can you please help me for the same?

Thank you.

Comment: please post another question with the code you tried!!!

Comment: Hi Sir,

I have done with create new question as below :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124027/use-controller-array-in-html-with-spring-boot

Please advice,

Thank you.

Comment: Hi,

please advice on this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169818/make-dynamic-query-with-jdbctemplate/35170739?noredirect=1#comment58189761_35170739

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot does not enforce you to use any sort of models. You can go with plain SQL queries.

Comment: Thank you for replying,
Do you have any example for the same?
I'm new in spring boot.. So..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the spring-boot-starter-jdbc like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and have auto configuration etc. enabled, you can inject an instance of `JdbcTemplate` and use its method to make SQL queries against your database.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for reply me.
Is there any example for the same because i have tried with your solution but i'm fail again and again.
Because i'm new on spring boot so...

Thank you.