# Use Controller array in HTML Table with Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

My Controller function return array successfully.

My Controller Code is :

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
ConfigurationController configcon = new ConfigurationController(jdbcTemplate);

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("users", configcon.getQuery("customers"));
    return "forward:/index.html" ;
}
```

But How to use this array (For ex., users) in webapp/index.html?

I want to display the database values in html table.

Please Advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a templating engine for that. Spring supports:

- Freemarker ([list, else, items, sep, break](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html))
- Groovy ([7. The MarkupTemplateEngine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_the_markuptemplateengine))
- Thymeleaf ([6. Iteration](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration))
- Velocity ([Foreach loop](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html#Loops))
- Mustache ([Non-Empty lists](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html))

*Source: [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines)*

These languages allow you to dynamically generate a HTML page based on your model. With Thymeleaf you could use the `th:each` attribute to loop over your model, for example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr th:each="customer : ${customers}">
      <td th:text="${customer.id}">&nbsp;</td>
      <td th:text="${customer.name}">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In this example I'm looping over the model `${customers}` (because you named it like that in your controller), and for each customer a row is generated with two columns, one for the ID and another one for the name. These represent properties (with proper getter/setter) in your customer class.

Each of the templating engines provide a different way for looping over your model, showing them all would probably be too much for this answer.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for reply.
Can you give me one example for edit form?
I have done with table.

Thank you once again.