# Make Dynamic Query with JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, jdbctemplate

I have one question regarding make dynamic query with JdbcTemplate.

My code is as below :

```
String insertQueries = "INSERT INTO " + tablename;

StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
StringJoiner joiner1 = new StringJoiner(",");
StringJoiner joiner2 = new StringJoiner(",");

while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();
        key = joiner.add((String) mapEntry.getKey()).toString();
        // value = joiner1.add("\"" + (String) mapEntry.getValue() + "\"").toString();
        value = joiner1.add("\"" + (String) mapEntry.getValue() + "\"").toString();
        value1 = joiner2.add("?").toString();
}

insertQueries += " (" + key + ")";
insertQueries += " VALUES ("+value1+")" ;

int row = jdbcTemplate.update(insertQueries, value);
```

Now my question is that I want same number of "value" as per auto generate question marks in insert query.

Right now, the value variable consider as one string so if I have 2 or more question marks then in value variable only one full string with comma separated so it's not working.

See below my query :

```
INSERT INTO tablename (fname, lname) VALUES ("abc, xyz") ;
```

And I want as below :

```
INSERT INTO tablename (fname, lname) VALUES ("abc", "xyz") ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**StringJoiner joiner2 = new StringJoiner(",", "(", ")");**
while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {

 //change in value1 as
value = "\"" + (String) mapEntry.getValue() +  "\"";
 value1 = joiner2.add(value);
 myvalue = joiner2.add("?");
```

}

```
 //change  insertQueries  as with value as (? ,?)
insertQueries += " VALUES "+ myvalue+"" ;


//get value1 as  ("abc", "xyz") 

//update query as
int row = jdbcTemplate.update(insertQueries, value1);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
But i want code like as below : 

insertQueries = INSERT INTO tablename(fname, lname) VALUES (?, ?) ;

And my code will be like as : 

jdbcTemplate.update(insertQueries, value);

And value dynamic generated with comma separated.

Please advice.

Comment: Hi,

Sorry it's still not working.
It still gives error like :

PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO tablename (last_name,first_name) VALUES (?,?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2

Comment: Please hard code the jdbcTemplate.update(insertQueries, value1) so that I can understand the inner parameter of update method

Comment: some thing like this            this.jdbcTemplate.update("update tablename set Fname = ? and lname = ?",  "abc", "xyy") - this is a different senario

Comment: No i just want to run insert query like as :

jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO tablename (fname, lanme) VALUES(?,?)", value1);

Comment: Did you hard-code and check it First for Different table - at-least 2 tables

Comment: Yes but still i'm fail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102548/discussion-between-chetan-nakum-and-jaskirat-singh).

Comment: Please refer the above this.jdbcTemplate.update as refer with 2 values

Comment: Means  this.jdbcTemplate.update instead of  jdbcTemplate.update 
Right?
Have you checked chat?

Comment: Sorry but this solution is not that i want.
Can you please help me on my code which i send you on chat?

Comment: Please please advice on my code sir if you have time .
Thank you

Comment: 1.You can go for the update and insert as different Query

Comment: 2. Use String insertQueries = "INSERT INTO " + tablename; and

Comment: String updateQueries = "UPDATE " + tablename + " Set ";

Comment: and Iterate in while Loop Accordingly.

Comment: Please See the Chat Discussion

Comment: Please See the Chat Discussion